# Get the specific text

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have to get the days between a specific date entered by the user, and the current date in a text box.

So, the simplest code as I think will be as follows:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
        TextBox1.Text = (DateTimePicker1.Value - Today).ToString
```

Now, suppose the user selects the date to be `02 March 2013`, then the result of this is like `11.12:48:21` but I just want the data to be like 11 i.e without the time.

I tried changing it to `Value.Day` and `Value.DayOfYear`, but it does not give the desired output.

I just want to calculate the number of days between today, and the user selected date in a dd or ddd or dddd manner.

Can someone guide me in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using this:

```
TextBox1.Text = (DateTimePicker1.Value.Date - Today.Date).Days
```

Just one word made so much difference.

Comment: okay, if you have a time you must read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), you can mark as _accepted_ your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like

```
 Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
        TextBox1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(-Today.Day).ToString("dd MMM yyy")
 End Sub
```

Comment: No, not this way. This doesn't give the days between two days. I solved it by,  TextBox1.Text = (DateTimePicker1.Value.Date - Today.Date).Days

Comment: so.. example: when we select a date `Feb. 20, 2013`. what should the output?

Comment: The output should be 0 if the user entered Feb 20 2013. When you select date as Feb 26, 2013 , the output should be 6 and so on. The whole point was to find the number of days between today, and the user entered date.

Comment: anyway.. you already figured it out your problem .. congratz `:D`

Comment: by the way, how do you highlight coding?

Comment: no.. you can't check my answer as accepted. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) the tutorial about formatting